# How to hide Lyx space annotation

Tags: lyx

If I insert "thin space" in Math mode, Lyx shows a "U" like symbol in place of the space. ( Note the symbol after the colon in following figure).

[image: Lyx space]

Is there a way to hide this symbol in Lyx?

If there are lots of spaces in the formula, it looks ugly in Lyx. ( Note that the formula looks fine in pdf. But I prefer to be in lyx view while editing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use [InstantPreview](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview) feature. When you finish editing a math inset, it will be rendered on the fly. See the [wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview) page for instructions.

Comment: Thanks. It works! However, preview size does not change if I zoom in or zoom out the document. It would have been nice to have the facility of regenerating the previews on document zoom.

Comment: AFAIK, it does not change with zooming. You can change preview size in the settings menu though.